# Envio de email automático de um site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Tenho uma hospedagem e meu site ja esta no ar, gostaria de saber se é possível programar o envio automático de email em um determinado horário, através do site.

Estou programando em aspx

Answer (score 4):

Sim, [usando o Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/).

O Hangfire pode agendar qualquer coisa, não apenas e-mails.

Você pode integrar o Hangfire com o [Postal.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Postal.Mvc5/), que produz e-mails como se fossem *Views*. Pode usar Razor ou ASPX.